# Can't use latest youtube-dl outside the install folder

Tags: python, environment-variables, youtube-dl

I recently installed youtube-dl from github: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

It works if I run it inside the install folder, like this:

```
$ cd /home/max/software/youtube-dl
$ bin/youtube-dl <url>
```

but if I try to use it anywhere else I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/max/software/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl", line 3, in <module>
    import youtube_dl
ImportError: No module named youtube_dl
```

This happens even if I give the full path to the executable.  I'd also tried copying the executable into `/usr/local/bin`, and making a symbolic link to it there.

Here's the actual contents of the exe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import youtube_dl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube_dl.main()
```

Is it something to do with which python it's loading perhaps? `which python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 1):

this post suggests some solutions for this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054500/how-to-use-youtube-dl-from-a-python-program

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```